# clustering l1 norm, k-medians

Tags: cluster-analysis

I would like to know how to show that the prototype $\mu_k$ that minimizes the cost function can be interpreted as the elementwise median (not mean) of the inputs assigned to the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to prove this yourself?

As far as I can tell, it should be straightforward.

1. Prove that it is sufficient to prove this in one dimension
2. Prove it for 1-dimensional data (= use the regular proof for the median)